# Wordpress Multisite error

Tags: wordpress

I’d like to create multiple sites on a single WordPress installation, each in a different directory. I tried to add a new website, filling in the required information:

Site Address: localhost/ flowers (in space)
Site Title: Flowers
Admin Email:
Then I click “Add Site”. The site seems to be added successfully, but when I try to visit the website’s dashboard, I get a 404 Not Found.

404 Not Found
Not Found

The requested URL /flowers/wp-admin/ was not found on this server.
Apache/2.4.9 (Win32) PHP/5.5.12 Server at localhost Port 80

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress Network doesn't work in different paths originally. The path that you filled is just a link for a site of the network in the same installation. You can give a subdomain for this site. E.g.

> sitename.domain.com

or use the path-based installation

> www.domain.com/sitename

even this option use a theme ou plugin previously installed in the network and shared for all sites. You can manage users and configuration of this site in the main panel.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Before_You_Create_A_Network

Comment: As per the link that you provided related to codex.wordpress I am restricted to directory and cannot create domain as my Wordpress address url is localhost.

Comment: @NupurSingh You can fix this issue with your hosts file if you're doing this locally by pointing the host to the name you want to.
I found these 2 links, hope it'll help you
http://lcblog.lernerconsult.com/2012-wordpress-3-multi-site-domain-mapping/
http://lcblog.lernerconsult.com/2012-wordpress-3-multi-site-installation-existing-web-sites/